# In Raphael, what's the difference between a Paper and a Raphael?

Tags: raphael

According to the [Raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html), there are two different entities `Paper` and `Raphael`. What is the difference between the two? Is it that "Paper" actually means "Raphael canvas" and "Raphael" refers to methods that can be done when the Raphael package is installed in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it you are spot on.  Paper is referring to a particular element that Raphael will render to.  Any Raphael methods are essentially static methods: they can be called without creating a paper instance.  You could have several Papers on any given web page, but you'll only have one Raphael.
A simple way to think about them may be that a Paper is a canvas, and Raphael is the library itself that has some static methods.